# What is difference between Myclass.class vs new MyClass()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-7, java-6

Team,
While learning java (specially generics),  i could see two different parameter in the method (.class and object reference) . When to use .class option and new myclass()? give me some example to understand

Comment: The `.class` is like have a sheet with the specifications of a car, the `new Class()` is when you actually need a car.  Use the `.class` when you want to refer to the specification. Use the `new` instance when you need to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new MyClass():` will create an instance/object of type MyClass

`MyClass.class:` is a "class literal" - a simple way of getting the Class for a particular type. in order to extract the metadata about the class such as fields and methods.

Refer to the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/jls10.pdf) for more details. (15.8.2 Class Literals)

Comment: thanks any idea which scenario we need to use. any examples

Comment: Like I said when you want some infomation about the class itself. 
a very basic use would be: To find the number of field and methods their names bla bla ...! https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html   This will help you with what you need! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 MyClass obj = new MyClass();
```

it returns a new object of type MyClass and will have all the global variables and methods defined in MyClass but,

```
Class obj1  = MyClass.class;
```

here obj1 cannot be treated as an object of MyClass.
obj1 is an object of Class.java(a class pre defined in java).
It does not have all the informations of MyClass.
but some methods defined in Class.java has some generic information of MyClass like:
`object.name` will give MyClass